# Invalid operands to binary int, float

Tags: c

I have this code

```
void estadistica()
{
    float suma=0,estadistic;
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        suma=suma+B[i];

    }
    estadistic=(B/suma)*100;
    printf("El valor de tu pedido es %f",estadistic);
}
```

and it says in estadistica

> error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and 'float')|

Comment: `B` is an array, you cannot divide it by a number `suma`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be nice of you if the code contained variable and function identifiers only in English language. Otherwise it is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `B` seems to be an array. In the following code :

```
estadistic=(B/suma)*100;
```

You are trying to divide an array (int *) by a float, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

B is an array. You can't divide an array by a float. You need to use a for statement.

Comment: No it is not, `suma` is declared as a `float`.

Comment: `suma` is a float.  `B` appears to be an array but we can't see the declaration.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wanted to say that.